# Need help understanding this last bit of assembly. (easy stuff)

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm still fairly new to assembly and I'm having some trouble understanding this last bit of assembly in a problem I am meant to solve (find the difference between the value of esp at the end of the code, and the location of the saved return address). From what I understand the first 5 lines are the functions "prologue" as it sets the base and stack pointers and then deviates (subtracts?) by the value 0xf8(248), making anything in between part of the new stack and pushing some registers onto it as well. However, I don't really understand what comes after that. I know its setting the stack pointer to different values but don't understand how the stack pointer can move around like that without breaking the program itself. Sorry for grammar or technical problems but I'm only a junior in high school with no background in comp sci and its fairly hard to wrap my head around this.

```
foo:
    pushl %ebp
    mov %esp, %ebp
    pushl %edi
    pushl %esi
    pushl %ebx
    sub $0xf8, %esp
    movl $0x1, (%esp)
    movl $0x2, 0x4(%esp)
    movl $0x3, 0x8(%esp)
    movl $0x4, 0xc(%esp)
```

Comment: The final 4 don't move the stack pointer at all, they just write some constants into memory relative to the stack pointer (into the space allocated by the `sub`).

Comment: One of your classmates asked a similar question in a now deleted question: "At the beginning of the function (after control is transferred via a call) _ESP_ points at the stack location where the return address is. Each `pushl` pushes 4 bytes on the stack reducing _ESP_ by 4 with each push. `sub $0xf8, %esp` subtracts 0x000000f8 from _ESP_. So it appears the difference would be -4-4-4-4-f8 = 0x108 = 264 decimal is the difference"

Comment: Thanks Michael, I already was under the impression that the last 4 lines were simply there to distract me and was just doing some reading on pushl which you just summed up nicely and in a digestible way. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're subjecting yourself to the abomination that is AT&T syntax.
It shoehorns Intel assembly code into a format [meant for the PDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmed_Data_Processor) (A processor first made in 1959).

In sane syntax this section looks like:

```
foo:
    push ebp               
    mov ebp,esp             //set up a stack frame
    push edi                //save some registers on the stack
    push esi
    push ebx
    sub esp, 0xf8           //push down the stack pointer to make space 
                            //for local variables
    mov dword ptr [esp],1      //local int1 = 1
    mov dword ptr [esp+4],2    //local int2 = 2
    mov dword ptr [esp+8],3    //local int3 = 3
    mov dword ptr [esp+12],4   //local int4 = 4
```

[If you are forced to use GAS you can restore sanity using](http://madscientistlabs.blogspot.co.za/2013/07/gas-problems.html)

`.intel_syntax noprefix` as the first pseudo-instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I have a small doubt. The question is to find difference between value of esp at end of code and location of saved return address.
I was thinking like this:

Assuming `x` to be return address (ebp)

```
mov %esp,%ebp   // basically x=esp=ebp
pushl %edi   //push statement so x+4 (since stack grows towards higher memory address)
pushl %esi   // now x+4+4
pushl %ebx   //x+4+4+4
sub $0xf8, %esp  //x+4+4+4+(0xf8-x)
```

Value of esp at end of code : `x+4+4+4+(0xf8-x)`
Location of saved return address we have assumed as x

Now the answer for this should be 260 right? Why do we have to take the first push (`push %ebp`) into consideration as well?

Comment: The saved return address is pushed on the stack as part of the  _CALL_ instruction. After transfer is passed to the function, _ESP_ will be pointing at the return pointer. The `pushl %ebp` simply pushes the value in _EBP_ onto the stack like any other register.

Comment: Please don't use answers to ask questions. If you wish to ask a question please start a new question. Thanks.